# MPMoviePlayerController in Background mode

Tags: iphone, background, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking

I am trying to play streaming file from particular URL using MPMoviePlayerController. It is working fine when I load the player but I need to keep it running when application enter into the background mode (Multitasking).  This is what I am doing:

```
-(void) playAudio :(NSString *)playAudioURL
{

    //NSURLRequest *audioFile = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:self.playAudioURL] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 10];  

    MPMoviePlayerController *mediaPlayer  = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:playAudioURL]];

    mediaPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill; 

    mediaPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    mediaPlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-bg.png"]];

    //[self.view addSubview:mediaPlayer.view];  

    mediaPlayer.fullscreen = YES; 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:mediaPlayer]; 


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(videoPreloadCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification
                                               object:mediaPlayer];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [mediaPlayer play];
```

}

Now when I press iPhone home button while running the audio, it pauses the streaming until I load back the Application. I need to keep it running when app enter into background.

Answer (score 1):

In your plist file, did you set the `UIBackgroundModes` key to audio ? Without this, your application will not play any sound in background

Note that in iOS5, `UIBackgroundModes` is now referenced as `Required background modes` when you edit your plist file.

Answer (score 0):

See [mpmovieplayercontroller-multitasking-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224823/mpmovieplayercontroller-multitasking-problem)